# django slugfield url error

Tags: django, django-urls

i get :
   Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
   ^ ^$
   ^ ^/(?P[a-zA-Z0-9]+) [name='view_blog_post']
   The current URL, duzeltme-yazisi/, didn't match any of these.

this error. 
here some outputs :

urls.py (in project folder) :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('userside.urls')),

)
```

urls.py (in app's folder) :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('userside.views',
    url(r'^$','index'),
    url(r'^/(?P<postslug>[^\.]+)','userside.views.singlePost',name='view_blog_post'),
)
```

views.py :

```
from userside.models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('userside/index.html',
                              {'post_list':post_list},
                  context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def singlePost(request,postslug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=postslug)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render_to_response('userside/detail.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
#from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import permalink

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
#    date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text  = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_blog_post',None, {'postslug':self.slug})
```

and here is my index.html template file :

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Mars</h1>
<br>
{% if post_list %}
    {% for x in post_list %}
        <p><a href="/{{ x.slug }}/">{{ x.title }}</a></p>
        <p>{{ x.text }}</p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="center">No records! ( but looks like code works correctly!)</div>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Django version  : 1.4

whats wrong here ? :/

thank you

Comment: which url are you trying to match?

Comment: i create a record from shell which title's is 'duzeltme yazisi'. it is in my main language. and in index page ,  i listed all the records. i add link to posts title in template file. when i clicked to title ; i should see the post specifically in another page which has slug url from post's title.

Comment: i added index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**project - urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', include('userside.urls')),
```

**userside - urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<postslug>[-\w]+)/$',
    # ../gis-grundlagen/
    view = 'singlePost',
    name = 'userside-single-post',
),
```

**userside - views.py**

```
def singlePost(request, postslug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=postslug)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render_to_response('userside/detail.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: thank you so much! it works! so it is about just get_object_or_404 ?

Comment: i checked. it is about 'userside.views.singlePost'; it must view ='...'.  thank you again.

Comment: get_object_or_404 is just shortcut within django so you don't need to check if the slug - given from the url - is available. You know...scriptkiddies...trying to crash the website...trying some urls ;)

Comment: I am in the similar position, and i can not understand what is `userside-single-post` here in the `userside - urls.py` ??

Comment: it's the URL's name. You could use that name in your templates like this `<a href="{% url userside-single-post post.slug %}">` As you can see I'm calling the URL and passing the slug-variable. You're also able to use that name in your views. There's a good example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a `$` when using include, try:

```
url(r'^', include('userside.urls')),
```

normally you would have a subfolder indicated, e.g.

```
url(r'^userside/', include('userside.urls')),
```

The initial slash (`/`) is probably also a mistake:

```
url(r'^/(?P<postslug>[^\.]+).html','userside.views.singlePost',name='view_blog_post'),
```

should likely be

```
url(r'^(?P<postslug>[^\.]+).html','userside.views.singlePost',name='view_blog_post'),
```

Comment: Update your question instead of trying to post code in the comment box (it just mangles the formatting to pieces :-)

Comment: Is "duzeltme-yazisi/" your slug? (Your urls.py is trying to match something ending in `.html`, but the href in your template is just `"/{{ x.slug }}/"`)...

Comment: yes. it is title of my post. title is duzeltme yazısı. so the slug is duzeltme-yazisi

Comment: i deleted .html extension in urls.py. but it is still same.